# Redux: async requests overwriting each other in the store

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, reactjs, redux, es6-promise

We are encountering a problem with async actions overwriting the store when they are slow and not the last request.

e.g.

we make a asny request to

`/posts?query=Hello`

then very soon after

`/posts?query=Hello World`

The results set for "Hello World" is much smaller then "Hello" therefore the previous request overwrites our redux store when it arrives after the later request...!

How can we get around this?

Pseudo code would be:

```
if (previousRequest == currentRequest) {
    previousRequest.cancel();
}
```

Although I know that `axios` or similar does not support cancelling requests, and how would I track this anyway...?

Comment: Just wondering, but is this related to a search box the user is typing into? And your example 'Hello' -> 'Hello World' is the result of the user typing?

Comment: Somewhat, in the exact case above yes, although there are cases where this also applies when we call a fetch in `componentDidMount` and then have requests via user interaction on the save view...

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/602 Are you using redux-thunk or redux-promise or similar middleware?

Comment: A few things come to mind. When you're fetching, do you set any state in redux that says you're currently fetching? Perhaps never start the request (or queue it) if one is already en route? Another option (more for the inputs where users are typing) is throttling the requests. Eg, don't send any requests until the user has stopped typing for x milliseconds.

Comment: @DustinStiles The user-typing-timeout approach is fine, but ultimately it just pushes the issue out to the edges a bit, e.g., any earlier async request could end up taking longer than a later request regardless of safeguards at the UI (or even Ajax timeout) level. Queueing results (or actions, or promises, etc.) is really the only viable solution that's solid all 'round.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan (Or redux-saga, which IIRC explicitly has a `takeLatest` doodad; it's the direction we're going to take, especially since we have to make a fair number of requests fairly often to a fairly laggy server.)

Comment: @DaveNewton that makes sense, thanks for insight

Comment: @DaveNewton yes Im using redux-thunk like middleware... is there a solution in there?

Comment: @DaveNewton one last question... how long did it take you to convert to sagas?